# Accessing the same data with multiple apps hosted in a shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have multiple apps that access the same folder. These apps are hosted in a shiny server, is there a way to let all/some apps access a specific path? Seems each app has only access to the folder they are contained in.

Comment: Yepp, you're looking for persistent storage. https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html

Comment: yes, shared local persistent storage, but it seems that each app is scoped within its folder. Im looking for a way to use local storage and make it available to the apps.

Comment: The closest thing that I can think of is an SQLite database located somewhere where apps might have access.